# jquery Split string / array

Tags: jquery

The cookie content looks like this:

```
{"array":{"id":"19111539","user_id":"91"}},{"array":{"id":"2551172","user_id":"91"}}
```

How to split it to have:

```
[0]{"array":{"id":"19111539","user_id":"91"}}
[1]{"array":{"id":"2551172","user_id":"91"}}
```

I tried cookie.split(','), but I cannot figure out why it does not print in the right order.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/55T3z/1/

Comment: WHAT  is this structure  ? it should be in array

Comment: @Satpal you changed his content to a wrapper array. and that's what im asking

Comment: @RoyiNamir, His content is not valid JSON, thus changed to wrapper array to guide him to towards solution

Comment: @Satpal I know it's not valid. but who said he's using json ? he has a string content which can be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put brackets around the value, that way it will be a valid JSON string that you can parse. The result is an array with two objects:

```
var cookie = '{"array":{"id":"19111539","user_id":"91"}},{"array":{"id":"2551172","user_id":"91"}}';

var arr = $.parseJSON('['+cookie+']');

console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[1]);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/KWCA2/

Answer (score 0):

I assume in cookie list of objects are stored as string with comma seperated.

```
 var cookieVal = '{"array":{"id":"19111539","user_id":"91"}},{"array" {"id":"2551172","user_id":"91"}}'; // Cookie value
     cookieVal = "[" + cookieVal + "]"; // Wrap it with Array brackets
 cookieVal = JSON.parse(cookieVal);
```

This will make them all wrapped in Array. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/55T3z/3/)